# Azure DevOps - PowerShell Output as File

Tags: azure, powershell, file, output, devops

I have written a PowerShell script in Azure DevOps to get all Azure Active Directory users as JSONM. I want to save the output as a JSON file in Azure repos.

My code:

```
Install-Module -Name "AzureAD" -Force
Import-Module -Name "AzureAD"
[string]$userName = 'TEST@TEST.TEST'
[string]$userPassword = 'TEST'

[securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force
[pscredential]$credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secStringPassword)

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credObject 

Get-AzureADUser | select @{N='email';E={$_.UserPrincipalName}} | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -FilePath .\UserExport.txt
```

Comment: Can you share the pipeline code you are currently using?

Comment: Sure shared the code.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

here is an example :

```
YOUR-COMMAND | Out-File -FilePath c:\PATH\TO\FOLDER\OUTPUT.txt
```

You seemed right to this, have you tried to see what it gives you in txt first ? Or it simply don't save the file ?

Comment: It dont save the file. I want to save the file in my devops repos. (Write a file would also enough for my task).

Comment: Hm... Can you give an example of the json ? By default the depth in "ConvertTo-Json" is 2.
EDIT : Reposted to make the code clear.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... Can you give an example of the json ? By default the depth in "ConvertTo-Json" is 2.
So you may have to change it like this :

```
Get-AzureADUser | select @{N='email';E={$_.UserPrincipalName}} | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File -FilePath .\UserExport.txt
```

Comment: the problem isnt the json structure. My problem is to save a file in Azure Repos with a PowerShell in DevOps. Save Files in devops do much problems for me..